# Обрезание переменной с конца до символа javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть строчка -123-4324-543-111, она в переменной, мне нужно обрезать строчку до знака "-" с конца, т.е что бы получилось "111". Не подскажете как?

Comment: Какие символы может содержать последний блок символов? Только цифры?

Comment: Не только цифры, это идет как ссылка на сайт т.е http://yandex.ru/google/123-4324-543-111

Comment: @Владимир спрашивали только про последний блок. Он всегда будет из цифр?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю такой вариант подойдет:

```
str = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
```

Comment: Да спасибо огромное, то что я и искал

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще вот так вот

```
var str = "-123-4324-543-111";
str.split("-").pop();
```

Comment: Очень хитро сделано :)